# How to simply print (write) text on a Surface in SDL.NET?

Tags: sdl

as i told in previous question, i'm using SDL.NET (wrapper in C# of SDL). Unfortunately the API website is down so i'm trying to learn it by myself. 
I would like simply to print text on my screen / surface ... i don't know how to do!

My goal is to print variable status/values, to "debug" directly on the run and on the screen (in the lower corner for example).
Can somebody help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution on an example project:

```
SdlDotNet.Graphics.Font myfont = new SdlDotNet.Graphics.Font("arial.ttf",12);
Point dest = new Point(600,400);            
surfVar = myfont.Render("Values: ",Color.White);
Video.Screen.Blit(surfVar,dest);
```

Comment: Heh, looks like we found it simultaneously :-)

Comment: when you can, be sure to make this the accepted answer so it isn't incorrectly categorized as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=8531.0 has an example of using Graphics.Font to render text to a surface (which is a wrapper for SDL_ttf I think). Basically you load a TTF font into a Font object and then use .Render on that to make a surface from a given string.